# UI design for mapping configurator

Tags: html, jquery

Looking to design an admin page that will allow users to map meta data between external and internal web service

We have internal process xml file that contain order details that may be fulfilled by different vendors

Current process is that all meta data from our internal file is mapped to external vendor web service params and this is stored in an xml file.

The application processing internal files, read the mapping xml files and use that to send in the right param values when invoking vendor web service calls.

I want to build a front end that will allow an internal employee to visually select the internal meta data file and then select the vendor service, which would list the methods and can map the internal meta data to external param input values. The hope is that it will reduce errors when creating the xml config file for processing service.

my set up uses backbone and jquery and would prefer not to use a jquery wizard or step plugin

Forgot to ask my question - I am looking for UI guideline/help as to how I could accomplish this development. I have looked around at system to see if any of those systems had a UI that would do something similar and I could use that as a jump board for my application but have not found much except for  step by step or wizard plug-in's

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a similar case about data mapping, with predefined data on the one side needed to be mapped one by one with external values which can be altered. 
A simple solution could be:

- user selects the data file -data are listed
- user selects the vector service - values are listed
- map data with value

[image]